# Automatically close dropdown when a new dropdown is selected/opened (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, state, react-hooks

I have a dropdown component and I'd like to be able to automatically close the previous dropdown when you click on a different dropdown menu item. I have the dropdown component working but I can't get them to close after selecting a new item. Additionally I'd like to close the items if you click anywhere on the page. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
export const Dropdown: FC<Props> = ({ passedBindings }) => {
  let [isDropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);
  const [ firstMediaBindings, ...restMediaBindings ] = bindings.mediaFlagBindings||[{}];

  const toggleDropdown = () => {
    setDropdownOpen(!isDropdownOpen)
  };

  return (
    <div { ...optionalAttributes }>
        <Container>
          {
            firstMoleculeMediaFlag()
          }
          {isDropdownOpen && restMediaBindings.length > 0 &&
            <Container passedBindings={({
              padding: {
                direction: "all",
                size: "size2"
              }
            })}>
              {
                restMediaBindings.map((mediaFlagBindings: IMoleculeMediaFlag, index: number) => {
                  return (
                    <Container
                      key={index}
                      passedBindings={({
                        padding: {
                          direction: "all",
                          size: "size1"
                        }
                    })}>
                      <MediaFlag key={index} passedBindings={mediaFlagBindings} />
                    </Container>
                  )
                })
              }
            </Container>
          }
        </Container>

      </Container>
    </div>
  )

``
```

Comment: "Anywhere on the page" could be achieved by a transparent modal div, or by on blur event; there are pros and cons though!

Answer (score 1):

You need a backdrop DIV to allow click and exit anywhere on the page.

It's like a 3-layer system.

- 1st : your page content
- 2nd : the backdrop goes on top
- 3rd : your dropdown goes on top of the backdrop

An example (using `styled-components` for style, but you can style as you wish):

**Backdrop.js**

This renders a div on top of your page content.

```
const Backdrop = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 100;
`;
```

Use it like that: conditionally with `isDropdownOpen`

**Dropdown.js**

But remember to style your dropdown with a `z-index` with something higher than the `z-index` you used on the backdrop. In this example, I used 100 for the backdrop so you can use 200.

```
export const Dropdown() {
  ...
  return(
    isDropdownOpen ?
      <Backdrop onClick={toggleDropdown}/>
      // Here goes the rest of your return for your dropdown
  );
}
```

If you need one dropdown to close the previous when they are clicked you need something in your `state` that tells you which one is opened.

Something like:

`const [indexDropdownOpened, setIndexDropdownOpened] = useState(false);`

You can set it to `false` (initial value) when no dropdown is opened, and you can set it with an `index` (or `key`) to tell your component which one is openend.

On each dropdown, when you render them:

```
...
return(
  <Container
    key={index}
    onClick={()=>setIndexDropdownOpened(index)}
  />
);
```

Then, on the backdrop, you could do:

```
<Backdrop onClick={()=>setIndexDropdownOpnened(false)}/> // So it closes the dropdown
```